# Mosby MVI - dependencies between presenters

Tags: android, mosby

I think the "problem" is valid for MVP as well, but in my case I try to sovle it for MVI.

**Use case**

I have a main view that shows list of data (each data is a list itself) and a detail view that shows a single items data list in a view pager.

I allow to delete items in the detail view, this means, I must update the detail view AND the main view (for example, the main view may show the number of sub items of each item, so this number must be updated)

**Question**

How can this be solved?

**Idea**

Each levels presenter subscribes to a global subject and the delete job sends a `MainPartialState` and a `DetailPartialState` to this global subject so that each view can update it's `ViewState` correctly.

Is there a better way to process partial states from inner levels in your app logic in outer levels as well?

Answer (score 0):

Both Presenter should observe the same Business logic part that manages the items. For example: Where do you load the items from? Are they loaded from a database? In that example a MainPresenter and DetailsPresenter observe the same database and whenever you delete an item from database both Presenter will be notified.

Comment: This means, I must have a shared (global) observable for both presenters and an event like `ItemDeletedEvent` is emitted to this observable and both Presenters are subscribed to this observable and will correctly transform this event to their respective partial state and then the state reducer will do the rest, correct?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-4

Comment: I did understand it that way. In favour of simplicity this results in a small side effect: you may have to do some work twice in both presenters. Therefore you get a decoupled logic